# Copying link list (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct n{//The definition of Linked List
    int x;
    struct n * next;
};
typedef struct n node;

int counter(node *r){ //Counting the node.
    int y=0;
    while(r != NULL){
        y++;
        r = r->next;
    }
    return y;       
}

//The problem is down there

void cpyLl(node *r){    //Copying link list
    int temp;
    for (int y = counter(r); y > 0 ;y--){
        temp = r -> x;
        while (r -> next != NULL){
            r = r -> next;
        } 
        r -> next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        r = r->next;
        r -> x = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    node * root;
    root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root -> x = 10;
    root -> next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root -> next -> x = 20;
    root -> next -> next =(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root -> next -> next -> x =30;
    root -> next -> next -> next = NULL;
    cpyLl(root);
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to copy my Linked list and it enter's on endless loop when i call cpyLl(); function.

My expected output is :

> 10 20 30 10 20 30

I actualy used function for node definition but i'm writing it in main for now.Because of code complexity.

I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11.

Comment: please explain the goal of _cpyLl_

Comment: @bruno i actualy did. it says copying link list right next to it.

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate the list at the end of the current list?

Comment: it means coppy the link list. cpy stands for coppy Ll stands for link list there's like 20 veriables and i do not slept so u know :/

Comment: @SefaKalkan I cannot understand what you said

Comment: I'm talking about my indention's @bruno

Comment: @SefaKalkan yes, and I cannot understand it. Out of that, I edited you code and there is a missing } in cpyLl

Comment: i'm trying to copy same link list to it's end. @drescherjm

Comment: The question is tagged as C++, so why is the code full of C'isms instead? This would a lot simpler using `std::list` or `std::forward_list` instead. At the very least, you should be using `new` instead of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cpyLl()`, you are not initializing the `next` field of each new `node` you allocate.  `malloc()` does not zero out allocated memory (if you want that, use `calloc()` instead).

Also, the `while` loop that you have inside the `for` loop to find the last node in the list really should be moved before the `for` loop is entered.  There is no reason to use the `while` loop on each `for` loop iteration, simply append the new node to the previous node you allocated.

Try something more like this instead:

```
struct node {
    int x;
    node *next;
};

int countLinkedList(node *n, node **last = NULL) {
    int count = 0;
    if (last) *last = NULL;
    while (n) {
        ++count;
        if (last) *last = n;
        n = n->next;
    }
    return count;
}

node* makeLinkedListNode(int x) {
    node *n = new node; // (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->x = x;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

void freeLinkedList(node *n) {
    node *next;
    while (n) {
        next = n->next;
        delete n; // free(n);
        n = next;
    }
}

void copyLinkedList(node *n) {
    node *last;
    for (int y = countLinkedList(n, &last); y > 0; --y) {
        last->next = makeLinkedListNode(n->x);
        last = last->next;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void printLinkedList(node *n) {
    while (n) {
        std::cout << n->x << " ";
        n = n->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    node *root = makeLinkedListNode(10);
    root->next = makeLinkedListNode(20);
    root->next->next = makeLinkedListNode(30);

    std::cout << "Before copy: ";
    printLinkedList(root);

    copyLinkedList(root);

    std::cout << "After copy: ";
    printLinkedList(root);

    freeLinkedList(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before copy: 10 20 30 
After copy: 10 20 30 10 20 30
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/j5LrUo)

That being said, you really should be using the standard C++ containers and algorithms instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void printLinkedList(const std::list<int> &l) {
    for(int x : l) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::list<int> l;
    l.push_back(10);
    l.push_back(20);
    l.push_back(30);

    std::cout << "Before copy: ";
    printLinkedList(l);

    std:copy_n(l.begin(), l.size(), std::back_inserter(l));

    std::cout << "After copy: ";
    printLinkedList(l);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before copy: 10 20 30 
After copy: 10 20 30 10 20 30
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/eaTYxu)

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler should be warning you of an unknown type `n` in:

```
struct n {  //The definition of Linked List
    int x;
    n * next;
};
```

Above the type for `n` is unknown at the time you declare `n * next;`. To remedy this, you need to include `struct` before the `n`, e.g.

```
struct n {  //The definition of Linked List
    int x;
    struct n * next;
};
```

This problem is also present in your `typedef`, e.g.

```
typedef n node;
```

Again `n` is unknown at this time. Instead you need.

```
typedef struct n node;
```

As bruno points out, you are invoking *Undefined Behavior* by using `x` in `counter` when it is uninitialized, e.g.:

```
int counter(node *r){ //Counting the node.

    int x;
    while(r != NULL){
        x++;             /* what is the value of x on the first iteration? */
        ...
```

Initialize `int x = 0` to remedy.

**Copy List Issues**

First do not put spaces around `->` in `r = r->next;` The arrow operator should directly connect the struct and member.

Your `cpyLl()` function doesn't copy anything. In order to copy a list, you need your function to return a pointer to the newly copied list. For example, it would make sense to do:

```
/* cpyL1 should return a pointer to the head of the newly copied list */
node *cpyLl (node *r) {
```

Within your function you need to allocate/create a new first node and assign the first data value for the copy and then essentially repeat for remaining nodes looping over all nodes creating a newly allocated node for copy and copying the value. You will need to preserve a pointer to the beginning of the copied list to return. You don't need `counter` at all within `cpyL1`. You have a linked list, you can iterate over the list using the `next` pointers. e.g.

```
/* cpyL1 should return a pointer to the head of the newly copied list */
node *cpyLl (node *r) {

    node *copy = NULL, *p;  /* pointers for new list - initialized NULL */

    if (!r) {   /* validate r is not NULL */
        fputs ("error: list to copy is empty.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    copy = malloc (sizeof *copy);   /* allocate 1st node of copy */
    if (!copy) {
        perror ("malloc-copy");
        return NULL;
    }
    p = copy;
    p->x = r->x;

    while (r->next) { /* copy all nodes from r to copy */
        p->next = malloc (sizeof *p->next); /* allocate each node */
        if (!p->next) {     /* validate the allocation */
            perror ("malloc-p->next");
            return copy;    /* return partial copy of list */
        }
        r = r->next;        /* advance to next node */
        p = p->next;

        p->x = r->x;        /* set node value */
        p->next = NULL;
    }

    return copy;    /* return pointer to newly copied list */
}
```

(**note:** you must VALIDATE every allocation.)

Now if you simply want to copy a specific node, then you can iterate until you find the value or address and simply copy a single node.

Putting it altogether and adding a print list and free list function, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct n {   //The definition of Linked List
    int x;
    struct n *next;
};
typedef struct n node;

int counter (node *r)   //Counting the node.
{
    int y = 0;
    while (r != NULL) {
        y++;
        r = r->next;
    }
    return y;
}

/* cpyL1 should return a pointer to the head of the newly copied list */
node *cpyLl (node *r) {

    node *copy = NULL, *p;  /* pointers for new list - initialized NULL */

    if (!r) {   /* validate r is not NULL */
        fputs ("error: list to copy is empty.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    copy = malloc (sizeof *copy);   /* allocate 1st node of copy */
    if (!copy) {
        perror ("malloc-copy");
        return NULL;
    }
    p = copy;
    p->x = r->x;

    while (r->next) { /* copy all nodes from r to copy */
        p->next = malloc (sizeof *p->next); /* allocate each node */
        if (!p->next) {     /* validate the allocation */
            perror ("malloc-p->next");
            return copy;    /* return partial copy of list */
        }
        r = r->next;        /* advance to next node */
        p = p->next;

        p->x = r->x;        /* set node value */
        p->next = NULL;
    }

    return copy;    /* return pointer to newly copied list */
}

void prnlist (node *l)
{
    while (l) {
        printf (" %d", l->x);
        l = l->next;
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

void freelist (node *l)
{
    while (l) {
        node *victim = l;
        l = l->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

int main (void) {

    node *root, *p, *copy = NULL;
    root = malloc (sizeof *root);

    /* first node */
    if (!root) {    /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-root");
        return 1;
    }
    root->x = 10;

    p = root;   /* assign pointer to root */

    /* second node */
    p->next = malloc (sizeof *p->next);
    if (!p->next) {    /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-p->next");
        return 1;
    }
    p = p->next;
    p->x = 20;

    /* third node */
    p->next = malloc (sizeof *p->next);
    if (!p->next) {    /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-p->next");
        return 1;
    }
    p = p->next;
    p->x = 30;
    p->next = NULL; /* set p->next to NULL */

    copy = cpyLl(root); /* copy root list to copy */
    if (!copy) {
        fputs ("error: copy is NULL\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    puts ("\noriginal list:\n");
    prnlist (root);
    puts ("\ncopy of list:\n");
    prnlist (copy);

    freelist (root);    /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
    freelist (copy);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/structfwd

original list:

 10 20 30

copy of list:

 10 20 30
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

Don't forget to validate your memory use for any errors.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/structfwd
==12148== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12148== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12148== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12148== Command: ./bin/structfwd
==12148==

original list:

 10 20 30

copy of list:

 10 20 30
==12148==
==12148== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12148==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12148==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 96 bytes allocated
==12148==
==12148== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12148==
==12148== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12148== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: in _counter_ you missed to say _x_ is not initialized (to 0)

Comment: and I don't speak about _cpyLl_ so 'strange' ^^

Comment: Who knows on that one `:)` Perhaps it is meant to be a mystery (*fingers crossed...*). The `for` loop could get real interesting with an uninitialized `x` in `counter`.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: Sure. Glad to help. Good luck with your coding -- and always initialize your variables `:p`

Comment: I edited the code can u please check it again @DavidC.Rankin.

Comment: Ok, give me a second and I'll drop an addition.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "*Your compiler should be warning you of an unknown type `n`" - that would be true in C, but not in C++.  A struct can refer to its own type without needing a forward declaration. And you definitely don't need to prefix a variable type name with `struct` in C++

Comment: He is trying to copy same link list to it's end.  So instead of returning copy, code should append the copy.
   r->next = copy;

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense, I took `cpyL1` to be `copy list 1`. (that and the title **Copying linked list (C++)**.